# How to get the values which are there in edit item template?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have  a control placed in **edit  item template** in detail view control. what ever the  control I am using I need to access those values in my code behind page that in my **item updating** event

Can any one tel me the syntax how to acces it those control values?

Actually what ever control are there in my   edit  item template   are not  added in my  designer.cs  file what is the  issue  for  this

thank  you

Comment: hi  tried  like that 
      TextBox lblID = (TextBox)dvList.Rows[1].FindControl("txtID");

? lblID   
when i type  this in my  immediate  window  it  gives
  the  value is  undefined

   but no  use

Comment: protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e) 
{ 
  TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Controls[0];//Name 
}
 tried  like this  but  still not  able  to get the value.
  is ther any  way  we  can  get the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will definitly work try..

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("YourControlID");
}
```